# How can I package the installed files in CMAKE

Tags: cmake

I install some files into a folder with CMake `Install` command. Then I want to package the folder into a `zip` or `tar`. How can i do it in cmake. I mean thar after executing the `make install` I can also get the zip file

PS：
I have tried

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND tar -cf ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.tar ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
                              WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})")
```

**But the install order of CMake is undefined across different directories**

Comment: and FYI, CMake's portable way to make a tar archive is `cmake -E tar ...`. The other commands by `cmake -E --help`... And if used from `CMakeLists.txt`, full path to CMake executable is in `CMAKE_COMMAND` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cpack`. The [easiest way](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cpack/Packaging-With-CPack) just `include(CPack)` into your root `CMakeLists.txt`, then `make package` would be available. Default formats exactly what you asked (`.zip` for Windows, various `.tar` for *NIX). To make other packages (RPM, DEB, MSI, EXE) you better to get familiar with documentation.

Comment: It will generate ${project_name}-0.1.1-Darwin.tar.gz also. It's only around  20B, contain nothing

Comment: @Samuel, please read docs/tutorials about using `cpack` properly. There is absolutely no need to use anything else (like manual running `tar`)!

Comment: I made a mistake, I install files in absolute path

Answer (score 1):

Since you the install order is undefined across the directories,you can try stating the dependency explicitly or make a list of all directories to be installed and use it in DEPENDS of your custom command which will install the package. cmake -P cmake_install.cmake will install the files to your directory.

```
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${tar_package}
        DEPENDS ${deps}

        # Install in a temporary dir
        COMMAND cmake
            -DCOMPONENT=${component}
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${install_dir}
            -P ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake
        # make tar or whatever you want
        COMMAND tar -czf
            ${tar_package}
            -C ${install_dir} .
    )
```